# How to get items from JList in the order they are selected?

Tags: java, jlist, mouselistener

I have a JList with `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` enabled and I'd like to pass the order in which the items are selected to another process.

I've tried using a `MouseListener` on the JList and checking if `getClickCount() == 1` then add it to an array, however, this will not add new items that are below the selected item, it only adds items that are above the currently selected item in the JList.

For example if my list looks like this:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

If I click number `1` first, then the below code will only show `1` for every subsequent click.  If I click `3` first and then click `5` the number that pops up is `3`.  If I click `3` and then click `2` or `1`, those numbers will popup correctly.

So I never actually get to the part of adding data to an array because I cannot get the data to display based up an action correctly.

Here is sample code from the listener:

```
private class ListBoxListener implements ListSelectionListener, MouseListener {

      @Override
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

         if(e.getSource().equals(aList)) {

            System.out.println(aList.getSelectedValue());
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(arg0.getClickCount() == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, aList.getSelectedValue());
         }
      }
}
```

Is there anything glaringly wrong with what I'm trying to do?

Comment: so when you clicked on number one, Joptionpane has to show 1 for example?

Comment: @KickButtowski yes and it will if it is the first one clicked or above another selectable number.

Comment: i am working on it but could you explain after and part ?

Comment: @KickButtowski I modified my question because your comment showed me an error in my question.  Please have another read and let me know if that clears up the confusion.

Comment: idk why my @ does not work. lemme reproduce your sample in my laptop and we wrok on it

Comment: @KickButtowski give me a few.  I'm trying to write a small compilable version for you to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59551/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-inquisitor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this code

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JList Test");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    String[] selections = {"Java", "C++", "C", "Scala", "JavaScript"};
    JList list = new JList(selections);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

            if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 1) {
                int index = list.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
                if (index >= 0) {
                    Object obj = list.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obj);

                }
            }
        }
    };
    list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understoud that you want to add an item listener to jList. So here is a simple code to show you how to do it:

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
jList1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        @Override
         public void valueChanged( ListSelectionEvent e){
                    if(! e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                            list.add(jList1.getSelectedValue());
                     }
          }
});
```